# Как получить все guid по дереву

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеются такие данные в бд, guid сокращу, что бы данные были более читабельны тут:

| guid | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| cc87.. | null |
| fd98.. | cc87.. |
| er43.. | cc87.. |
| lo32.. | er43.. |
| ds12.. | ds12.. |
| db23.. | ds12.. |

Как вывести все guid, где родитель cc87.. ?
В Итоге должен получиться столбец, состоящий из fd98.. er43.. lo32..
Как то так
PS:

```
WITH tree (Id, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT s1."Id", s1."Name", 0 AS Level
    FROM public."Table" s1 WHERE s1."Id" ='206c6843-d918-422e-8085-16e8de5ad093'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s2."Id", s2."Name", Level+1
    FROM public."Table" s2 
    INNER JOIN tree ON tree."Id" = s2."ParentId"
)

SELECT * FROM tree
```

Comment: Да самый обычный рекурсивный CTE... причём простейший, вообще без наворотов.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался!

Comment: Когда пишу в CTE вызов этого же шаблона появляется ошибка relation "tree" does not exist

Comment: Дописал так WIHT RECURSIVE и заработало